# Faut-il ajouter le pronom en : "Elles sont multiples" ou "Elles en sont multiples" ?

Tags: pronoms

> Les lois de comportement des milieux sont celles qui définissent les relations entre les déformations et contraintes. Elles sont multiples.

ou

> Les lois de comportement des milieux sont celles qui définissent les relations entre les déformations et contraintes. Elles en sont multiples.

Je me demande si on doit ajouter en ou non. Pourquoi oui ou pourquoi pas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il n'y a pas d'antécédent justifiant la présence du pronom ***en*** ici. La phrase correcte est donc:

> Elles (les relations) sont multiples.

Remarque, à la fin de la première phrase, on utilise soit deux articles :

> *...qui définissent les relations entre **les** déformations et **les** contraintes*

soit aucun article :

> *...qui définissent les relations entre déformations et contraintes*.

Answer (score 0):

Au sens général, le pronom apparaît tel un prédicat réitéré. En effet, on ne saisit pas ce qui est multiple. Quel lien entre les deux phrases ? Pour quoi utiliser ce pronom ?

La formulation est inadaptée avec ou (et) sans pronom, car on ne saisit pas la signification. En ce cas l'effet produit est inverse à celui recherché ou escompté (voir ci-après).

- Ce sont celles qui *définissent* les relations multiples. Une loi permet en principe de réduire la complexité. A l'inverse, ***une*** corrélation peut exprimer quelque chose de multiple.

En outre, le pronom (elles) remplace normalement le sujet de la phrase précédente (les lois).

Comment: Merci. J'ai upvoté. Juste pour clarifier : "Les lois de comportement des milieux sont celles qui définissent les relations entre les déformations et contraintes. Elles sont multiples." Je l'ai trouvé dans un livre sur la mécanique des milieux continus d'un auteur locuteur natif du français. Ma question portait sur le fait si l'on doit ajouter en ou pas. Je n'ai pas imaginé que la formulation est inadaptée.